# Counting the frequency of Numbers by Term Document Matrix in R

Tags: r, tm, term-document-matrix

I started using `tm` package and have got a question in the Term Document Matrix function.
I know that with this function, we can get the frequency of words across a set of documents. But I have noticed that it doesn't show the frequency for "**NUMBERS**". It currently shows the frequency of only **ALPHA-Numberic** terms.

Please let me know what am I missing here.

Comment: please share some data

Comment: a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). Because tm can show the frequency of numbers.